# How do I allow the user to transform a function set by desmos API?

Tags: javascript, frontend, graphing

I am trying to show how the difference in an equation can transform a function. I am using the desmos API from here https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.5/docs/index.html for the graphing. However, I want it to display a set function and allow the user to change aspects of it.

For example: Upon entering the site, the graph displays f(x)=(ax+h)^2-k . I want the visitor to be able to only input h, k and a. The graph would show the new graph with the values the user put in. If you have an alternative to desmos API, it is also accepted.

```
var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);
calculator.setExpression({ id: 'graph1', latex: 'y=x^2' });
restrictedFunctions = true;
```

Comment: But isn't it the whole point of an API? You pass it parameters and it replies accordingly. Pass it values for h, k and a, and the API will reply with the corresponding graph. I don't get exactly where you're stuck? Where's the code corresponding to your problem?

Comment: I don't want the visitor to change the initial equation. I want f(x)=(x)^2 to not change. I only want the other values to be changeable.
Another example is f(x)=|x+1|+2. I only want the visitor to be able to change values in the place of 1 and 2. x and the || shouldn't be altered.

Comment: Well then, write this code to use the API accordingly. Set the initial equation, ask the users the values of h,k and a, then query the API with these parameters, and get the response. Again, _this is precisely what an API is made for_, so not only it is possible, but it is _the whole point_ of it. Again, we can't help you unless you show the code relevant to your question because... well we're just blind, we have no idea what you wrote.

Comment: var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
  var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);
  calculator.setExpression({ id: 'graph1', latex: 'y=x^2' });
  restrictedFunctions = true;

This is all I've done so far. I am completely lost as to what to do next

Comment: I moved the code to your question. But didn't you create `<input>` fields? If you want your users to input numbers, then you need these in your HTML. Then I guess you can simply graph the result with `{ latex : "(" + a + "x+" + h + ")^2 - " + k }`

Comment: Hmmm, well that's a completely different problem. If you have no idea how to create a HTML form, how to read the value of an input field etc. then there's just too much for one question. You should follow a few tutorials about that first

Answer (score 0):

Each expression has a bunch of different properties like `latex` & `secret`. One of them is `readonly`. It makes the expression, well, read-only. Add some sliders, & use some JavaScript to make sure that the latex is of the form `[Your Variable Name]=[Number]` & undo if it isn't. Undo if it has the wrong number of expressions.

Edit: Instead of using JavaScript to force sliders to be sliders, just make them readonly.